# Python CSV Reader with quotes and newlines inside field

Tags: python, parsing, csv

Here's my code:

```
in_reader = reader(open(csv_in))
for row in in_reader:
    ...do stuff...
```

It throws _csv.Error complaining of newline in string when it gets to a line like this:

```
asdf,"asdf",asdf,"asdf"
asdf",asdf
```

Note that not all fields are quoted, and the problematic field here is basically a quoted field that contains a quote and a newline.

Comment: I'm confused by what I should be doing with that sample too, and I'm a human.  Isn't the quoting properly closed in the first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a proper CSV file. It's trying to read `asdf"` as the first field of the second record, and failing.

If there's a quote within a quoted string, it needs to be escaped (often as two double quote characters: `""`).

Comment: Hmm, yea I guess it's just not valid CSV.